# Swift Package Dependency: "No Such Module..." - Why?

Tags: swift-package-manager, swift-package

**Goal:** To learn how to add an import to a Swift package. 
**Modus Operandi:** Use an Apple-supplied Example as base.  Add another import (i.e., Alamofire) 
**Result:** Alamofire does import; but its module "can't be found".

The Package:

[image]

The Sources:

[image]

**Question:**
Why is this happening? 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Check the target `DeckOfPlayingCards`, select the `General` tab, check `Framework, Libraries, and Embedded Contents`, make sure `Alamofire` is on the list

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `.target` section in your `targets` section in `package.swift` file, add your dependencies as like array objects

```
.target(
        name: "DeckOfPlayingCards",
        dependencies: ["PlayingCard", "Alamofire"]),
```

This solved my problem. I was also having the same issue showing `No such module "Alamofire".` Not only Alamofire but also every other. I forgot to put my dependencies there.

I hope this will help someone sometime.